# Написать код поиска максимального элемента в массиве Ассемблер

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Можете описать по строчно код нахождения максимального элемента в массивк Ассемблер. Ниже прилагю код

```
   DATA SEGMENT
   ARR DB 1,4,2,3,9,8,6,7,5,10
   LEN DW $-ARR
   LARGE DB ?
   DATA ENDS
   CODE SEGMENT
   ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE
   START:
   MOV AX,DATA
   MOV DS,AX
   LEA SI,ARR
   MOV AL,ARR[SI]

   MOV LARGE,AL
   MOV CX,LEN

   REPEAT:
   MOV AL,ARR[SI]
   CMP LARGE,AL
   JG NOCHANGE
   MOV LARGE,AL
   NOCHANGE:
   INC SI
   LOOP REPEAT
   MOV AH,4CH
   INT 21H
   CODE ENDS
   END START
```

Comment: "Кто-то может?"..это и есть вопрос?.. Ответ: "Да, кто-то определенно может")

Comment: Сформулируйте конкретно с чем у вас возникают трудности, чтобы вам могли помочь. Пока что вопрос слишком общий как мне кажется.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATA SEGMENT
ARR DB 1,4,2,3,9,8,6,7,5,10
LEN DW $-ARR
LARGE DB ?
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE
START:
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
LEA SI,ARR
MOV AL,ARR[SI]
MOV LARGE,AL
MOV CX,LEN
REPEAT:
MOV AL,ARR[SI]
CMP LARGE,AL
JG NOCHANGE
MOV LARGE,AL
NOCHANGE:
INC SI
LOOP REPEAT
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```